# How to avoid null values wrapping inside double quotes in WSO2 ESB foreach Mediator?

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I am facing an issue with the WSO2 ESB foreach mediator where null values are being wrapped inside double quotes in the resulting JSON payload. I want to avoid this and keep the null values as they are without any wrapping.

Here's the code I am currently using:

```
<enrich>
    <source clone="true" xpath="json-eval($.list[*])"/>
    <target type="body"/>
</enrich>

<foreach expression="json-eval($)">
    <sequence>
        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>
                {
                "Sample1": "$1",
                "Sample2": "$2",
                "Sample3": "$3",
                "Sample4": "$4"
                }
            </format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.SAM1"/>
                <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.SAM2"/>
                <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.SAM3"/>
                <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.SAM4"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
    </sequence>
</foreach>

<enrich>
    <source type="body" clone="true"/>
    <target type="property" property="records"/>
</enrich>
```

The response I am getting currently is:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "Sample1": "value",
            "Sample2": "value",
            "Sample3": "null",
            "Sample4": "null"
        }
    ]
}
```

The null values are wrapped inside double quotes, which is not what I need. I want the null values to remain as they are without any wrapping as follows,

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "Sample1": "value",
            "Sample2": "value",
            "Sample3": null,
            "Sample4": null
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried different approaches to solve this issue. However, none of those things worked.

Anybody can help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the following before responding.

```xml
<jsontransform>
   <property name="synapse.commons.json.output.autoPrimitive" value="true"/>
</jsontransform>
```

If you want to have more control over what data points get converted you can add a JSON schema to the JSON Transform Mediator. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75662425/2627018) answer and [this](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/json-Transform-Mediator/) document.

With the schema the transform mediator will look like this. Add thie before responding back to the client.

```xml
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
<jsontransform schema="json-local-entry"/>
   <property name="synapse.commons.json.output.autoPrimitive" value="true"/>
</jsontransform>
```